# App crashes while accessing an element from array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

Im using the following piece of code to add elements to array dynamically.

```
for (response in jsonDic[@"value"][@"options"]){
                 NSMutableArray *notifyText = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
                 [notifyText  addObject: jsonDic[@"value"][@"options"][response]];
                 NSLog(@"it is%@",notifyText[1]);
             }
```

When i try to access using `notifyText[1]` ,what is the logic that I'm missing?

Comment: Can you show me your response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have create the `notifyText` Array every time so it is every time alloc and add only one value

please Do like

```
 NSMutableArray *notifyText = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
for (response in jsonDic[@"value"][@"options"]){
                 [notifyText  addObject: jsonDic[@"value"][@"options"][response]];
                 }
 NSLog(@"it is%@",notifyText[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Indices in array start with 0. First element has index=0. Try

```
 NSLog(@"it is%@",notifyText[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you are allocating MutableArray named "notifyText" inside for loop,which is being allocated every time ,for last value it is initialized and object is added at 0 index and you are trying to fetch from index 1,that is why app is getting crashed.Do one thing alloc array above the for loop or in ViewDidLoad method.